# SIGSYS Bad System Call (Android)

Tags: android, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, inline-assembly

I am writing some inline assembly code for Android and while stepping through the code using GDB in an x64 Android emulator, I see the syscall I tried to execute got a `SIGSYS Bad System Call` error. I tried running the code as a standlone executable (not an Android application and also running it in the emulator) and it works properly without error.

I searched online for the error code and online articles seem to point to seccomp. Does seccomp play a part in limiting what syscall I can make? Where can I find out more details about this?

My code snippet is as follows

```
    char *filename = "/system/bin/sh";
    int f_ok = F_OK;
    int ret_val;

#ifdef __x86_64__

    __asm__ volatile(
            "movq $21, %%rax\n\t"
            "movq %1, %%rdi\n\t"
            "movq %2, %%rsi\n\t"
            "syscall\n\t"
            "movq %%rax, %0"
            : "=m"(ret_val)
            : "m"(filename), "m"(f_ok)
            : "%rax", "%rdi", "%rsi", "cc", "memory"
            );

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "inline_assembly", "ret_val %i", ret_val);
```

I based the usage of the syscall number on this link (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#x86_64-64_bit).

I am not sure if the error is caused by my code or seccomp. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't just call the `access()` function?  Also note that your clobber list is incomplete (add `rcx` and `r11`); this may cause further problems down the road.

Comment: Seems weird to ask for the args in memory instead of `"D"(filename), "S"(f_ok)`.  (You could ask for them in `"r"` reg inputs and still keep the `mov` instructions, but it's better to just have the compiler put them in the regs you want).  Also, you're storing 64 bits to a 32-bit `int ret_val` memory output operand, potentially stepping on surrounding variables.  Use `"=a"(ret_val)` without the `mov`.  (And you can use an `"a"(__NR_access)` input operand to get the compiler to put the call number in RAX for you, from `#include <asm/unistd.h>`  Or `SYS_access` from `<sys/syscall.h>`

Comment: The list of allowed system calls should be [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:bionic/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT). For processes spawned by Zygote (and only for them) you get some more allowed calls. The list should be [this one](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:bionic/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT). `access` is only on the latter.

Comment: Hi @MargaretBloom

It seems that both of the links you shared point to the same page?

Comment: Hi @fuz

I am concerned about the access function being hooked (inline hooking or using PLT and GOT) so I am exploring using inline assembly instructions.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes

Thanks for your guidance. I am not familiar with writing inline assembly so I used what seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process gets a SIGSYS, it means that a syscall filter is installed. So, yes, it is definitely related to [seccomp(2)](https://manpages.org/seccomp/2).